# MySQL update rows if each columns equals the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this :

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|                Actions                                 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| action_id | user_id | action_active | action_cancelled |
----------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |    1    |       0       |         0        |
----------------------------------------------------------
|     2     |    2    |       1       |         0        |
----------------------------------------------------------
|     3     |    1    |       0       |         0        |
----------------------------------------------------------
|     4     |    2    |       0       |         0        | 
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to update all action_cancelled to 1 for a user_id, if a user has each of his rows as action_active = 0. 
If he has at least one action_active as 1, don't update.

In this example, it should update action_cancelled to 1 for the row 1 and 3, because the user 1 has each of his action_active at 0.

I thought about something like this, but I'm not sure about how right it is :

```
UPDATE actions 
SET a.active_cancelled = 1 
WHERE (SELECT p.user_id, SUM(p.action_active) as sum_p FROM actions p GROUP BY user_id WHERE a.user_id = p.user_id AND sum_p = 0);
```

I'm getting stuck there in the WHERE. How can I say "if a user has all of his rows as action_active = 0, update them"

Would love some help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` and `JOIN` to do it

```
    UPDATE actions a
    JOIN 
   (
    SELECT p.user_id, SUM(p.action_active) as sum_p 
     FROM actions p 
     GROUP BY user_id
     HAVING sum_p = 0)
   b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
    SET a.action_cancelled = 1
```

Comment: @Komarzer just updated it,removed `where` in subquery

Comment: And active_cancelled by action_cancelled by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
update t
     set t.active_cancelled = 1 
where not exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.user_id = t.user_id and t1.action_active = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solutions is,

```
update actions
inner join(
    select user_id,sum(if(action_active=1,1,0))as inactive from actions group by 
    user_id having inactive=0
)as B on B.user_id=temp.user_id
set actions.action_cancelled=1;
```

Comment: I think you mean actions.user_id instead of temp.user_id ? Seems to be working like this